# Append document to iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, xmlhttprequest

I am currently receiving parts of a webpage through an XHR, and then parsing them using the [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser). After this I change some of the elements, but I am failing to append the document to the iFrame.

The document that is parsed is all right, but when appending this document to the iFrame by calling `iFrame.contentDocument = parsedDocument`, `iFrame.contentDocument` stays empty (actually there are html, head and body tags but their content is empty).

I am parsing the received data like so:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var parsedDocument= parser.parseFromString(xhr.response, 'text/html');
```

And my expectation was to do something like this:

```
iFrame.contentDocument = parsedDocument;
```

Comment: And if you write to it? `var doc = document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(parsedDocument);
doc.close();`

Comment: @epascarello It now shows up `[object HTMLDocument]` in the iFrame.

Comment: @MarijnS95 You should try `xhr.response` instead of `parsedDocument` then. `parsedDocument` is a `HTMLDocument` object, while you want to write the actual string instead, otherwise it will try to write `HTMLDocument.toString()` which will return `[object HTMLDocument]`.

Comment: Duh, on my part since it is an object...You would have to pull out the html string...

Comment: @Joeytje50 But how am I gonna manage the changing of the elements then?

Comment: @epascarello When using .toString() it also returns me a `[object HTMLDocument]`. So how should I pull the html string out of the document?

Comment: @MarijnS95 I know how to fix it, I'll post an answer

Comment: @MarijnS95 no it would not be toString() you would have to access the content in the parser. Something like `parsedDocument.documentElement.outerHTML` but that would exclude the doctype if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like epascarello said in the comments, the following will work:

```
var doc = document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(xhr.response);
doc.close();
```

But, since you need to modify the document before placing it inside the iframe, you'll first need to do this:

```
//your code
var parser = new DOMParser();
var parsedDocument = parser.parseFromString(xhr.response, 'text/html');
//put your required edits here
parsedDocument.getElementById('foo').style.color = 'red'; //example
//now to get back the edited HTML code as a string
var newHTML = parsedDocument.documentElement.outerHTML;
//and now for the code epascarello mostly wrote
var doc = document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(newHTML);
doc.close();
```

You might also want to specify a doctype there, by replacing the line of `doc.write(newHTML);` with:

```
doc.write('<!DOCTYPE html>'+ newHTML);
```

since the `document.documentElement.outerHTML` won't contain the doctype with it.